# VAT on Web Services outside EU?

Tags: taxes, vat

Do I have to collect VAT for web services as an EU based company (Austria) from customers outside the EU?

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is late. VAT and other consumption tax are usually levied on products and services that are **purchased and used/utilised** in the country (or group of countries, as in the EU) that applies the tax.

So, to answer your question, customers outside the EU will **not have** to pay VAT and you should not collect any. If the person you are selling your services to is a business, they would have to pay the relevant consumption tax in their country (depending on the country's legislation), but that is out of your scope.

You can refer to this website for more information:
http://europa.eu/youreurope/business/vat-customs/cross-border/index_en.htm